# Finding your previous questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow

How do I find a question I asked 10 days ago? I logged on today using Google and it seems I now have a different ID (usernnnnn)! I think I'm running under a different ID than when I left the question (at which time I also used Google). Why is my old username (from years ago) not being displayed either?

And the display of my activity makes it sounds like I'm a new user (with only one logon).

Comment: I've HAD an account for several years, which seems to have disappeared with this new openid. I would LOVE to have a real username instead of usernnnn. Then maybe I could find my previously asked questions. So I now need to create ANOTHER username?

Comment: If you started a new account today, your questions will be tracked from now on.

Comment: As I've said, I HAD an account before you went to openid. When I logged in several days ago, I apparently (though it doesn't say this) logged in under a temp ID. I had no way of knowing this because I was forced to use an openid site. So, to repeat my question, how do I find the question I created several days ago and, even better, my history of open questions. I am NOT a new user.

Comment: Do you have any information we could use to help find your old account? Posts that were on it? Its name? Anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648003/ron-hoeflinger. Looks like you have a Stack Exchange OpenID linked to it as well as a Facebook login. So, to log back in, choose "log in with Facebook" and use what I presume is your one and only Facebook account. (Some people have multiples.)

If you're still having trouble, drop us an email via https://stackoverflow.com/contact and we'll get you going again.